# Thinkpad X1 Extreme Gen 2 w/ 4K screen daisy chaining two 4K monitors vs one Thunderbolt 3 port?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, thinkpad

I have a [Lenovo X1 Extreme Gen 2 laptop](https://psref.lenovo.com/syspool/Sys/PDF/ThinkPad/ThinkPad_X1_Extreme_2nd_Gen/ThinkPad_X1_Extreme_2nd_Gen_Spec.PDF) with [NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 4GB](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/graphics-cards/gtx-1650/#specs) GPU, a 4K screen, and Thunderbolt 3 ports.

My goal is to add two more 4K monitors to this setup by using only one Thunderbolt 3 port by daisy chaining them together.

Thunderbolt 3 supports chaining 4K screens. But, how do I figure out if the GPU will support this?

I've read that the GTX 1650 supports 7680x4320@120Hz but does not specify what this means in a multi-screen setup (and with a 4K screen built-in already). Is 7680x4320 the max resolution for *each* screen? Or for them combined? Or something else?

Since I can chop up 7680x4320 into four 3840x2160 displays, does this mean that three 4K screens is no problem? If not, how do I figure out what screen configurations are supported?